# avoid Linkbutton control inside repeater to postpack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater that has a LinkButton control inside it, and an OnItemCommand event using this linkbutton.

I want this LinkButton not to cause a postback on page or repeater.
I have tried some solutions but none works.

Is this possible to achieve, how?

Comment: Why do you use a `LinkButton` then and not a `HyperLink`? What should happen at all when the user clicks on it?

Comment: When clicked the linkbutton must get the item ID, make some alghorithm, and trigger a modal box. I guess I could not do this with a hyperlink, not sure.

Comment: so you want to do that with javascript?

Comment: Javascript or other, yes. Thats a problem I will deal later, if I can

Comment: Well, if you can't do it at client-side the whole question is pointless because you have to do it at server-side(postback). Maybe you want to avoid the flickering(`UpdatePanel`) or you have another issue which you haven't mentioned(f.e. reloading initial data after postback). Then this is a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: With a `Hyperlink` you can execute javascript

Comment: I do want to stop flickering and also the reordering of tables repeater. How can I use updatePanel to avoid flickering?

Comment: Then use an `UpdatePanel` to load the content of the Repeater asynchrounosly. So only the issue remains that the repeater uses the inital sort. Put the databinding code in `if(!IsPostBack){ DataBindRepeater(); }`

Comment: Do you mean placing the repeater inside an UpdatePanel? I ve done that before, and now again. Still is flickering.

Comment: then ask another question with the aspx-code with the repeater and the updatepanel. There must be a reason for the flickering

Comment: Hi again Tim, I did solve the flickering problem already, thanks for your help. Still the reordering issue is important for me. The only way to solve this would be using JS? can you give me some directions here, would I need to perform the complete server-side alghoritm in JS?

Comment: Learn here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use OnItemCommand event without causing postback.

Use updatepanel if you want to use OnItemCommand or you can perform what you need using javascript.

Comment: I can use update panel, but how will that help me here?

Comment: Are you concerned with postback user experience or by server side code itself ?

Comment: right now my concern is that the repeater postbacks. This will undo any ordering or filtering made by user

Comment: You can store the filtering and ordering parameters and re-do it on every postpack